# Create column based on file name

Tags: r

I have thousands of files I need to do this for so I am trying to avoid doing this manually for each file. The only identifying characteristics in these files is the file name so I need to create a column based on the file name so they can be identified when I combine the files later. The file name contains a placeholder then the boat name then the net number separated by an underscore. My data looks like this:

file name = 3_Whip_1.1.csv (Boat = Whip, Net = 1.1)

```
Time     Pred
11:00    10.2
12:00    8.4
13:00    9.6
```

I would am trying to get the data to look like this:

```
Boat    Net    Time     Pred
Whip    1.1    11:00    10.2
Whip    1.1    12:00    8.4
Whip    1.1    13:00    9.6
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to return a substring of the 'filename' and split it into two columns with `read.table` and `cbind` with the original data

```
d1 <- read.table(text=gsub("^\\d+_|\\.[^.]+$", "", filename),
         sep="_", col.names = c("Boat", "Net"))
cbind(d1, dat1)
#   Boat Net  Time Pred
#1 Whip 1.1 11:00 10.2
#2 Whip 1.1 12:00  8.4
#3 Whip 1.1 13:00  9.6
```

#### data

```
dat1 <- structure(list(Time = c("11:00", "12:00", "13:00"), Pred = c(10.2, 
 8.4, 9.6)), .Names = c("Time", "Pred"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

filename <- "3_Whip_1.1.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun This works great for splitting up the file name once I have extracted it. The part I am really stuck on is getting the actual file name into a data frame. Rather that just creating each data frame individually through, filename <- "3_Whip_1.1.csv".

Comment: @D.Chamberlin  You can get the filenames from `list.files()` if it is in the working directory and read all the files in a list i.e. `filenames <- list.files(pattern = ".csv"); lst <- lapply(filenames, function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE); dat1 <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, filenames, lst))` and then split up the columns

Comment: @D.Chamberlin Fwiw, making a table to contain the file names and their metadata is another way to go: `fileDF = data.frame(list.files(patt="csv$")); fileDF$id = 1:nrow(fileDF); fileDF$Boat = sub(...)` etc. (An example with data.table http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#rbindlist-read )

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work for one data frame. You probably can create a function to include these operations and loop through (or use `apply` family function) a vector or list of your filenames. The `list.files` function can show all filenames in one directory, which could be useful for your work.

```
# Create the example filename
filename <- "3_Whip_1.1.csv"

# Create example data frame
dat1 <- data.frame(Time = c("11:00", "12:00", "13:00"),
                 Pred = c(10.2, 8.4, 9.6),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Remove ".csv"
filename2 <- sub(".csv", "", filename)

# Split the string by "_"
filename_vec <- strsplit(filename2, split = "_")[[1]]

# Create columns to store the information
dat1$Boat <- filename_vec[2]
dat1$Net <- filename_vec[3]

# Change column order
dat1 <- dat1[, c("Boat", "Net", "Time", "Pred")]
```